# PHP's function date() not working properly? (unexpected output)

Tags: php, datetime

I've noticed that one of my scripts that depend on the function date() fell into an infinite loop. While investigating the cause of this, I came up with a very simple an surprising test:

```
<?php
echo (date("Y-m-d H:i:s",1330221136)."\n\n");
echo (date("Y-m-d H:i:s",1330222036)."\n");
```

Since the first timestamp is smaller than the second, the first line was supposed to return an earlier datetime. However the out put for the code above is:

```
2012-02-25 23:52:16 

2012-02-25 23:07:16
```

Does anybody know about any malfunctioning of the function date() in PHP 5.3?

Comment: This could be due to [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Take a look at using [DateTime](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and ][DateTimeZone](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

Comment: I just output something different:
http://codepad.org/Q30jafcM

Comment: @wes: That's because codepad is on another time zone than the OP.

Comment: @jon: yes, but in the example above, it's the same hour. Mine is not.

Comment: @wes Yes because we're in different timezones, the point is that the second is greater than the first.

Comment: I'm able to duplicate it if you set the timezone to America/Buenos_Aires. Very interesting...  Edit: Oh, I see why in the answer below.

Comment: [but Argentina has no DST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2012.html)

Comment: to answer this, we need to know your timezone

Comment: guys, my timezone is UTC/GMT -3 hours (Brazil's official timezone)

Comment: @PauloMárioAndrade: This behavior should be completely expected. You 've just uncovered a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could legitimately happen if the clocks were turned one hour backwards at exactly 00:00 local time. So:

1. Your code has a bug, because it does not allow for the possibility of this happening
2. It seems that in your local time zone DST ended on 2012-02-26 00:00 (local time)
3. Which lets us know that you are located in Brasil (props to **Fluffeh** for finding out!)

Comment: This was my first train of thought as well, so I went to sifting through ghastly google results, but I found this for San Paulo: Daylight Saving Time, DST ended on Midnight between Saturday, February 25, 2012 and Sunday, February 26, 2012 local daylight time.

Comment: There's your answer then @Fluffeh, clocks obviously went back at midnight, hence there being two 23:**

Comment: @Fluffeh: So we also learned that the OP is located in Brasil.

Comment: @Jon Have a +1 on me to make up for it :)

Comment: which doesnt mean the answer is wrong. It's very likely a DST issue.

Comment: It IS a DST issue. Thanks guys! I'd have never thought of that!!

Answer (score 1):

A copy/paste to my installation gives this as a result:

```
2012-02-26 02:52:16
2012-02-26 03:07:16
```

That seems fine to me.

Comment: i have the same.. 2012-02-26 02:52:16 AND 2012-02-26 03:07:16

Comment: @Jon's answer explains that dude